# XSLT Remove node based on another node's attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file, I need to remove ContentText element with the attribute languageCode="FR", if the ContentText element with the attribute languageCode="EN" exist else keep the French text.

Current XML :

```
<MaterialByElementsResponse_sync>
  <Material>
    <Detail>
        <ContentText languageCode="FR">Inscription</ContentText>
        <ContentText languageCode="EN">Subscription</ContentText>
    </Detail>  
  </Material>   
</MaterialByElementsResponse_sync>
```

Desired Output :

```
<MaterialByElementsResponse_sync>
  <Material>
    <Detail>
        <ContentText languageCode="EN">Subscription</ContentText>
    </Detail>  
  </Material>   
</MaterialByElementsResponse_sync>
```

---

I tried this XSLT but it is always deleting the FR text even if the EN text doesn't exist :

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ContentText[@languageCode='FR']"/>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Remember if there is no English text, the French text shouldn't be removed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I added my current XSLT to main topic. You can take a look.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<xsl:template match="ContentText[@languageCode='FR']"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="ContentText[@languageCode='FR'][../ContentText[@languageCode='EN']]"/>
```